# Creating entity in database with unmapped property

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, breeze

The entity model I'm working on is structured with inheritence as per:

```
public abstract class Line {}    
public class WooLine : Line{
   public bool wooProperty{ get; set; }
}

public class BooLine : Line
```

These are both stored in the database in the table Line. And in the database the column wooProperty is NOT NULL and default value (0).

These are maintained in a web app written with Knockout & Breeze. When working with BooLine trying to create a new entity, it throws an exception that I can't insert NULL into column wooProperty.

I set up a profile to trace the query, and it appears that since it's mapped to the Line table, during the Insert EntityFramework reads up all the properties and tries to actually insert NULL into the wooProperty, since it's not present in the Boo model. I'm moderately upset that EF is actively trying to insert NULL to a property I'm not working with...

Anyway. I can't move the wooProperty to the Line model - it belongs in the WooLine model. I'm hoping to solve it by either modifying the metadata in Breeze or forcing the wooProperty onto the saveChanges data. But I can't get breeze to recognize the property in the metadata. I've tried to run

```
    metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor(
        'BooLine', function () { 
            this.wooProperty = false;
        });
```

Which almost works - but Breeze maps it as __unmapped value and as such isn't recognized after being recieved by EntityFramework.

I also started playing around with overriding the EFContextProvider and overriding BeforeSaveEntity. Entity is ReadOnly of type BooLine, and I can clearly see WooProperty in the UnmappedProperties, but I have no idea where to go from there... Any ideas?

TLDR in a way; Want to 'trick' entity framework into thinking an unmapped value is mapped when creating an entity.

Comment: IMO your problem is in your DB: If  `wooProperty` is not part of all entities which use the `Line` table via TPH it can't be `NOT NULL`. EF uses a discriminator column to determine the actual type of a row...

Comment: I know what you mean, but it really can't be allowed to be null when working with it through the WooLine, so it wouldn't make sense to allow it to be null. It's overcome with a default value in most normal cases.

Comment: If you mark it as `[Required]` EF should take care of it never beeing `null` in case of a `WooLine` (and `bool` can't be `null` anyhow)...

Comment: It depends on where I expose the model to though. And while c# doesn't allow nullable bool values, it might cause problems reading from the database if the column is null there. How would EF behave if it's trying to interact with the table and there are nulls in its Required field, which'd be the case for BooLines? Modifying the table and making it nullable would be the absolute last-resort...

Comment: ...but EF will not read it if it is not a (valid) `WooLine`. If your datamodel is valid and you only access the DB via EF there shouldn't be a problem. If you also access the DB  without EF you need to take care there to only create valid rows. Maybe you could also switch to TPT inheritance? For TPH EF uses the discriminator column and that must be set correctly for EF to distinguish between `WooLine` and `BooLine`...

Comment: TLDR in a way: Do not 'trick' a 3rd-Party library in doing something it's not supposed to do - sooner or later it will bite you... ;-)

Comment: Well, the tldr aside (it was a bit difficult to summarize ;) ) I think you're right in that per definition the TPH structure requires all columns not shared between types to be nullable. Mildly annoying. So I'll follow your advice in making the code-side of the WooLine Required and leaving the database column Nullable. Cheers :)

Comment: I've posted a summary as an answer for easier future reference...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize my comments I would recommend one of the following:

- make your model use TPT inheritance so there is no `wooProperty` column in the `Line` table, but in the inherited `WooLine` table
- change your `wooProperty` column to be nullable and mark the `wooProperty` property in your entity class as `[Required]` and let EF take care of reading only "valid `WooLine`s" - this should work if there is also a valid discriminator column for EF to use